# What is an "early catholicism"?

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches, new-testament

My basic understanding of "[early catholicism](http://www.oxfordbiblicalstudies.com/article/opr/t94/e568)" is that it is a paradigm for understanding the development of parts of the New Testament, with some parts coming later as early expectations were unmet and the original apostles began to die off. I'm looking for a fuller definition, though.

What are the main features of "early catholicism" and what reasons are there for adopting this as a paradigm for understanding the development of the New Testament? Does this paradigm hold much weight among scholars today?

Comment: I'm no scholar, but this is a great question to look into. I need to get some more history via the findings and answers to this. Thanks. +1

Comment: I've added a link: does the linked definition match what you intended by the term?

Comment: Here's another link to go with the Oxford. http://www.theearlycatholicchurch.com/

Comment: @JackDouglas Yes, that's the term I'm asking about.